# Lagrangian of non-linear 3 mass, 2 spring system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, non-linear-systems

Given 3 masses connected by 2 springs with the angle of intersection constant, but the springs themselves bending.

Young's modulus, which is a variation of Hook's Law, applies to the flexing that would occur given the constant angle of intersection.

The tricky thing about Young's modulus is that while the angles between the springs may be constant at the central mass, the relative angles between the three masses is variable due to flexing of the springs.

The Lagrangian of 3 masses, 2 springs, but no Young's modulus:

$$KE= \frac12 MV^2$$

$$PE=\frac12 k x^2$$

$$L=\frac12 M_1V_1^2+\frac k2(l_1-(x_2-x_1))^2+\frac12 M_2V_2^2+ \frac k2(L_2-(X_3-X_2))^2+\frac12 M_3V_3^2$$

What terms will be needed to account for the angle as well as the bending motion?

Obviously both x and y will be involved since it is 2D.